# Custom Navbar - CSS skill, Bootstrap responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I desperately need to make a navbar as on this photo:

[image]

I have no skill in CSS to make it right, specifically if I don't want this brand logo to be png or jpeg but made in css.

Also i need this navbar to be responsive using boostrap. Fixed to top.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

PS. if you scroll down there should be a little gradient, like on stackoverflow site.

Gradient at bottom line of fixed top navbar look like below:

[image]

Comment: Well that “logo” is trivial to achieve using border-radius.

Comment: This is too broad of a question. Please post some specific code, in a codepen or a fiddle, that you're having issues with and i'll be glad to help.

Comment: Actually @CBroe it's a little bit more difficult then that if you take into account the padding/margins.

Comment: I dont have skills to make this exactly navbar made in html/css. That is why i ask for help. Thanks

Comment: Well then you need to acquire some skills, and the best way to do that is to go and try stuff. You should _at least_ be able to show us a code example of this navigation with some basic formatting applied already. Same as your previous question, this is so far pretty much a “I can’t, you make” type of post - and that is not what StackOverflow is for. This site is for _developers_ to ask _specific_ questions about specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.border {
  
  /* the border you need (as box-shadow) */
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(12,13,14,0.15), 0 0 0 transparent, 0 0 0 transparent, 0 0 0 transparent;

  /* fixed to top */
  top: 0px;

  /* make it responsive */
  width: 100%;

  /* basics */
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fafafb;
  height: 60px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

Comment: If you want the gradient when scrolling down, you mean increase the size of the bow-shadow. You have to add a class with js after scrolling down.